# import excel sheet in winform

Tags: c#

I am using oledb connection string to import excel sheet. I am referencing 12.0 object libraries.
I tried with excel 2003 and 2007 both but getting same exception as below

Creating an instance of the COM component with CLSID {00020820-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} from the IClassFactory failed due to the following error: 80010001.

my code is

```
        txtpath.Text = fdlg.FileName;

        Excel.Worksheet worksheet = new Excel.Worksheet();
        Excel.Sheets sheets;
        Excel.Workbook theWorkbook;
        string SheetName;

        OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=\"" + txtpath.Text + "\";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=Yes;\";");
        conn.Open();

        Excel.Application ExcelObj = null;
        ExcelObj = new Excel.Application();

        theWorkbook = ExcelObj.Workbooks.Open(txtpath.Text, 0, false, 5, "", "", true, Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", true, true, 0, true, 1, 0);

        sheets = theWorkbook.Worksheets;

        worksheet = (Excel.Worksheet)theWorkbook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
        SheetName = worksheet.Name.Trim();

        OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter("Select * FROM [" + SheetName + "$]", conn);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);
```

please help.

Comment: In which line does the error occur? Beside, your second line (`Excel.Worksheet worksheet = new Excel.Worksheet();` looks supsipicous, simply declare a new variable and don't call `new` on the `Worksheet` type. Only the `Excel.Application` object can give you a new worksheet.

Comment: 20xA3: it looks like he never uses the new-ed up worksheet; the reference is overwritten by the call to `theWorkbook.Worksheets.get_Item(1)`. I'd say it's probably leftover experimentation. That said, if the *error* is there.... could be the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a very low-level COM error, RPC_E_CALL_REJECTED, "Call was rejected by callee".  That doesn't help much, but clearly Excel isn't very happy with your code.  A very good candidate is this statement:

```
 Excel.Worksheet worksheet = new Excel.Worksheet();
```

Lose that, it doesn't do anything useful.  Creating the Application object first is always required.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I don't do a lot of Office interop. But my Googling on this error implies that it occurs when the COM object in question isn't fully loaded, and I note that you're opening the connection *before* you're creating an `Excel.Application` object.

Perhaps you can switch that around? Try something like this:

```
        Excel.Worksheet worksheet = new Excel.Worksheet();
        Excel.Sheets sheets;
        Excel.Workbook theWorkbook;
        string SheetName;

        Excel.Application ExcelObj = null;
        ExcelObj = new Excel.Application();

        theWorkbook = ExcelObj.Workbooks.Open(txtpath.Text, 0, false, 5, "", "", true, Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", true, true, 0, true, 1, 0);

        sheets = theWorkbook.Worksheets;

        worksheet = (Excel.Worksheet)theWorkbook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
        SheetName = worksheet.Name.Trim();


        OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=\"" + txtpath.Text + "\";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=Yes;\";");
        conn.Open();
        OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter("Select * FROM [" + SheetName + "$]", conn);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);
```